# Did the TYPE_NAME function change any data in my database

Tags: sql-server, select

I was trying to find out the data type for certain columns in a table. I used the `TYPE_NAME` function because that's what I found online that was supposed to help me. I ran a query like the one below to get that information:
`select TYPE_NAME(a.account_name) from account a`

But I didn't get the usual results, instead I got:

> Commands Completed Successfully

Did I accidentally change data in the table? I thought that you couldn't do that with `SELECT` statements? Any help would be hugely appreciated

Comment: `SELECT` doesn't change data.  It's strictly a read.

Comment: Possibly you hit the Parse button instead of the Execute button.

Answer (score 2):

The argument to TYPE_NAME is a type_id, the integer key in sys.types.  To see the type of a column.  You use the TYPE_NAME function like this:

```
select name column_name, type_name(user_type_id) type_name
from sys.columns c
where object_id = object_id('Person.Address')
```

Comment: So did I accidentally change something in the database?

Comment: You can't change a column type with a SELECT statement.  ALTER TABLE is the only way to change a column type.

Comment: That's what I thought! Thanks so much for that input!

Answer (score 1):

If you ran a **only** a `select` using *type_name(...)* and nothing else then no data was updated or added. It is possible to use a `select` to `insert` or `update` data though. Ex `insert into dbo.Table (ID) select 1`

Comment: Ahh yeah I've seen that used before. I definitely didn't use an insert or update statement. I appreciate that!